# Putting values in the Map

Tags: salesforcedx, map

I am trying to put some values in the Map for learning purpose but getting some error , i am not sure i am following the correct way or not .

```
   public static Map<String,String> monthMap=new Map<String,String>(){
     'January'=>'01',
     'February'=>'02',
     'March'=>'03',
     'April'=>'04',
     'May' =>'05',
     'June'=>'06',
     'July'=>'07',
     'August'=>'08',
     'September'=>'09',
     'October'=>'10',
     'November'=>'11',
     'December'=>'12'
};
```

Error : For each and Every Line it is giving me error as : Expecting ';' but was: '=>';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```java
new Map<String,String>(){'January'=>'01'};
```

Use

```java
new Map<String, String>{'January'=>'01'};
```

[Apex Developer Guide Maps](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_maps.htm)

> As with lists, you can populate map key-value pairs when the map is declared by using curly brace `{}` syntax. Within the **curly braces**, specify the key first, then specify the value for that key using `=>`.

Comment: Thanks its working , but still have question in my mind sometime it's work but sometime not?

Comment: @AbhijeetKumar It should work. If it does not work then the reason is something else.